# window.addEventListener in angularjs controller cause to call twice or more

Tags: javascript, angularjs, addeventlistener

I use `window.addEventListener` in a AngularJs controller to bind event listener, but the problem is that when i go to another state and back to this state, the event listener function called twice and repeats, because of binding event listener multiple times.

This is my controller code:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receivePosMessage, false);
```

I want to `receivePosMessage` invoked after `window.postMessage`. so i used `addEventListener`.
How can i solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I also added `window.removeEventListener("message", receivePosMessage, false);` before `addEventListener` but didn't worked!

Comment: You need to remove the `event` when leaving the page

Comment: @firatozcevahir, please check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with adding theses below code into controller:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    window.removeEventListener("message", receivePosMessage, false);
});
```

This solution was given by dear [@cody-mikol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10860795/cody-mikol).